# HBase tables not shrinking as expected

Tags: java, hbase

I have a stand alone instance of HBase (no hadoop) running on a single
machine.

It was originally at 32G, after updating some of the column definitions
from the shell:

```
alter 'table', {NAME =>'mycol', TTL => <two_months>}
alter 'table', {NAME =>'mycol', COMPRESSION => 'GZ'}
```

The data store has grown overnight from 32G to 51G (not caused by new data!). I'm expecting the table to shrink as most of the entries are older than two_months. In addition I have requested compression on the column.

I'd like to understand why running the alter command has caused the massive increase in size and can I expect it to shrink again?

I was expecting it to shrink at the next major compaction, it has been > 24 hours and I'm
surprised it's not yet happened.

Comment: Have you tried manually running a major compaction of the table? Also you may want to poke around the html administration pages

Answer (score 1):

For TTL issue just force a major compaction as juhanic stated. Compression is trickier though since hbase doesn't have a method to auto merge blocks yet (there are issues about it in jira), your number of blocks (regions) would not change. When I switch compression I prefer to export -> truncate -> re-import data.

Small hint : If size is a problem easiest optimization is lowering the VERSIONS value (to 1 if possible). I guess you did that already.

Comment: Thanks, using versions is an option, ttl is preferable.